# How to append a new column to csv payload using dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I'm downloading a huge `csv` file from Azure blob and I want to transform the data by adding an new column and then uploading the transformed `csv` file to another location.

Since it is a huge file with around 42 columns the application fails or restarts when trying to transform.

Can someone suggest how can I achieve this use-case?

Input in `csv`

```
col1,col2,col3....col41 10,23,asds....29 34,83,hdkd....57 so on
```

Expected Output in `csv`

```
NewCol,col1,col2,col3.....col41 1023,10,23,asda......29
3483,34,83,hdkd......57 so on
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please inform how the file is being downloaded? HTTP, SFTP, other? Thanks.

Comment: How it fails? Please add any error messages in the logs, complete, as text.

Comment: Is your question about how to resolve the error or about how to add a column?

Comment: I'm getting the data from the azure storage connector. I tried the transformation to add the column but when I run it on cloudhub I get this error "[warning] PersistedLongArray(fileName: `dw-buffer-index-5.tmp` is being GCed but is still open. It is going to be closed to avoid tmp leaks." and the application gets restarted. As mentioned I have 41 columns.

Comment: Could you please update your question with a screenshot of your flow? Thanks

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of flows but XML text. Screenshots for sources are not recommend in Stackoverflow. Also clarify the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To add a column to the CSV output you just need to add the field to each row:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
payload map ($ ++ { NewCol: $.col1 ++ $.col2})
```

Comment: To prevent using disk and improve streaming, you should be able to add `streaming=true` on the input (you can use a set-payload and replace the mime-type by adding this parameter) and `deferred=true` as an output parameter in the DW script. https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-streaming

Comment: To add to @JorgeGarcia comment, you can even try adding a simple for-each and inside it,  add the new column to the payload and write it to csv. The batch size value of for-each is configurable, this will help you to  funnel the huge payload into smaller chunks and perform your logic , there by avoding any out-of-memory issues.

Comment: I would evict the batch unless it makes sense in the bigger use case because it will break the streaming. The same can happened with for-each if it's not well handled because you need to rebuild the full structure again if you transform row by row. Also, transform row by row is extremely slow.